# How to increase table inside images using html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created one table using HTML.

Table Details :

First row   : I inserted one image.

Second row : some contents.

Again i write one row.Third row successfully added.Row content is large , so table automatically increase the size but first row image not increase.

How to increase the image at table content based?

Thanks,

Kumar R

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a CSS rule like this?

```
table img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Maybe it's just a CSS problem.

Comment: I have added this code but not working.                                                 img {
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: I have posted my html code following link.please see the link.                                    Link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836852/how-to-increase-image-size-based-on-table-contents-using-html

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
table img {
  width : 100%;
  height : auto;
}
```

Demo :

```css
.tg td {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
table img {
  width : 100%;
  height : auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      some content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      some laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried following code:                                                                       <table  align="center" width="640px" style="width: 640px; padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px; background-color: #17B8DD">
<tbody>
 <tr>
     <td style="width:100%;">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="85%" style="padding-top:10px">
 <a href="http://www.s.com">
            <img src="http://KB/logo.png" alt="S Inc." style="height:auto; width:auto" sizes="80vw"/>
</a>
</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
      </td>
       </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

Comment: Hi Daniele Petrarolo ,                                                                                                                 I have create one table , again i create one table inside of first table.                      First table I write one image. second table i write content.

Comment: Hi Munawir ,      
I have posted my html code following link.please see the link. Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836852/how-to-increase-image-size-based-on-table-contents-using-html